# Azure Search - Additional Stop Words

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When creating an index definition in Azure Search, is there any way to add additional stop words just for that index. For example if you are indexing street names one would like to strip out Road, Close, Avenue etc.

And if one makes the field non-searchable i.e. the whole thing is indexed as one term, then what happens to something like Birken Court Road. Would the term being indexed be Birken Court.
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an additional set of stopwords using a [custom analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search).
For example,

```
{
 "name":"myindex",
 "fields":[
    {
       "name":"id",
       "type":"Edm.String",
       "key":true,
       "searchable":false
    },
    {
       "name":"text",
       "type":"Edm.String",
       "searchable":true,
       "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
    }
 ],
 "analyzers":[
    {
       "name":"my_analyzer",
       "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
       "tokenizer":"standard_v2",
       "tokenFilters":[
          "lowercase",
          "english_stopwords",
          "my_stopwords"
       ]
    }
 ],
 "tokenFilters":[
    {
       "name":"english_stopwords",
       "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.StopwordsTokenFilter",
       "stopwordsList":"english"
    },
    {
       "name":"my_stopwords",
       "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.StopwordsTokenFilter",
       "stopwords": ["road", "avenue"]
    }
 ]
}
```

In this index definition I'm setting a custom analyzer on the *text* field that used the *standard* tokenizer, *lowercase* token filter and two *stopwords* token filters, one for standard english stopwords and one for the additional set of stopwords. You can test the behavior of your custom analyzer with the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer), for example:

request:

```
{
   "text":"going up the road",
   "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}
```

response:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "going",
      "startOffset": 0,
      "endOffset": 5,
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "up",
      "startOffset": 6,
      "endOffset": 8,
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Analyzers are not applied to non-searchable fields, therefore the stopword in your example would not be removed. To learn more about query and document processing see: [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture).

Comment: Many thanks. Very helpful. Is there any way to create an analyzer that will remove the stop words but keep everything else intact. i.e if stop words include "Road", then the analyzer to tokenize : Birken Court Road as "Birken Court". Thanks again.